# How to fix: NameError: name 'on_key_release' is not defined? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I was typing in some code (as most of us do) from a book, but when I ran it, I got this error: `NameError: name 'on_key_release' is not defined`. I typed it in perfectly, but it still won't work, and I know that I have defined it. It may be because the book is for python3 and I have python2. The full error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\caleb.sim\Downloads\Sim Inc\Sim Inc\Applications\Games\Ball and Bat\BallAndBat.py", line 97, in <module>
window.bind("<KeyRelease>", on_key_release)
NameError: name 'on_key_release' is not defined'
```

Here is the code:

---

```
import tkinter
import time
canvasWidth = 750
canvasHeight = 500
window = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width = canvasWidth, height = canvasHeight)
canvas.pack()
bat = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 40, 10, fill="dark turquoise")
ball = canvas.create_oval(20,0,30,10, fill="deep pink")
windowOpen = True
score = 0
bounceCount = 0
def main_loop():
    while windowOpen == True:
        move_bat()
        move_ball()
        window.update()
        time.sleep(0.02)
        if windowOpen == True:
            check_game_over()
leftPressed = 0
rightPressed = 0
def on_key_press(event):
    global leftPressed, rightPressed
    if event.keysym == "Left":
        leftPressed = 1
    elif event.keysym == "Right":
        rightPressed = 1
def on_key_press(event):
    global leftPressed, rightPressed
    if event.keysym == "Left":
        leftPressed = 0
    elif event.keysym == "Right":
        rightPressed = 0
batSpeed = 6
def move_bat():
    batMove = batSpeed * rightPressed - batSpeed * leftPressed
    (batLeft, batTop, batRight, batBottom) = canvas.coords(bat)
    if (batLeft > 0 or batMove > 0) and (batRight < canvasWidth or batMove < 0):
        canvas.move(bat, batMove, 0)
ballMoveX = 4
ballMoveY = -4
setBatTop = canvasHeight - 40
setBatBottom = canvasHeight - 30
def move_ball():
    global ballMoveX, ballMoveY, score, bounceCount, batSpeed
    (ballLeft, ballTop, ballRight, ballBottom) = canvas.coords(ball)
    if ballMoveX > 0 and ballRight > canvasWidth:
        ballMoveX = -ballMoveX
    if ballMoveX > 0 and ballLeft < 0:
        ballMoveX = -ballMoveX
    if ballMoveY > 0 and ballTop < 0:
        ballMoveY = -ballMoveY
    if ballMoveY > 0 and ballBottom > setBatTop and ballBottom < setBatBottom:
    (batLeft, batTop, batRight, batBottom) = canvas.coords(bat)
        if (ballMoveX > 0 and (ballRight + ballMoveX > batLeft and ballLeft < batRight) or ballMoveX < 0 and (ballRight > batLeft and ballLeft + ballMoveX < batRight)):
            ballMoveY = -ballMoveY
            score = score + 1
            bounceCount = bounceCount + 1
            if bounceCount == 4:
                bounceCount = 0
                batSpeed = batSpeed + 1
                if ballMoveX > 0:
                    ballMoveX = ballMoveX + 1
                else:
                    ballMoveX = ballMoveX - 1
                ballMoveY = ballMoveY - 1
    canvas.move(ball, ballMoveX, ballMoveY)
def check_game_over():
    (ballLeft, ballTop, ballRight, ballBottom) = canvas.coords(ball)
    if ballTop > canvasHeight:
        print "Your Score Was: " + str(score)
        playAgain = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(message="Do you want to play again?")
        if playAgain == True:
            reset()
        else:
            close()
def close():
    global windowOpen
    windowOpen = False
    window.destroy
def reset():
    global score, bounceCount, batSpeed
    global leftPressed, rightPressed
    global ballMoveX, ballMoveY
    leftPressed = 0
    rightPressed = 0
    ballMoveX = 4
    ballMoveY = -4
    canvas.coords(bat, 10, setBatTop, 50, setBatBottom)
    canvas.coords(ball, 20, setBatTop-10, 30, setBatTop)
    score = 0
    bounceCount = 0
    batSpeed = 6
window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close)
window.bind("<KeyPress>", on_key_press)
window.bind("<KeyRelease>", on_key_release)
reset()
main_loop()
```

---

(That was a pain to format!)

Any help would be appreciated!

-Caleb Sim

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define on_key_release.

Over here, I can see that you defined on_key_press twice.
did you mean to define one of them as on_key_release?

```
def on_key_press(event):
    global leftPressed, rightPressed
    if event.keysym == "Left":
        leftPressed = 1
    elif event.keysym == "Right":
        rightPressed = 1

def on_key_press(event):
    global leftPressed, rightPressed
    if event.keysym == "Left":
        leftPressed = 0
    elif event.keysym == "Right":
        rightPressed = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, judging by the code in your question, you have not defined `on_key_release`. You have `on_key_press` copy-pasted twice, so one of those might have been meant to be changed though.

Also: You can format code by highlighting it and using the {} button on the top bar.